# File extension in bootstrap validation

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4, bootstrapvalidator

I'm working on validation here the added Docx extension but when I select docx file then still showing an error. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here

```
upload: {
           validators: {
              file: {
                 extension: 'doc,docx,pdf,zip,rtf',
                 type: 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/rtf,application/zip',
                 maxSize: 5*1024*1024,   // 5 MB
                 message: 'The selected file is not valid, it should be (doc,docx,pdf,zip,rtf) and 5 MB at maximum.'
              }
           }
        },
```

Comment: Pls check Mime type of the file, dont see filename

Comment: @RyanNghiem I added Mime/type `,application/msword` here where I have to add? Can you explain me little more where I have to add?

Comment: Not code, you should check your file that is selected

Comment: @RyanNghiem Yeah, my file is docx file only.

Comment: Can you show full code or link demo same like your code?

Comment: @RyanNghiem this is codepen link https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/qBWzYLe?editors=1010

Comment: You should add codepen link into the question to others follow

Comment: I select my docx file then form submit successful :)

Comment: @RyanNghiem Yeah, now I got it. I don't know before i getting an error thanks for the help.